# Access Specific Attributes of a Div Using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to access a specific set of attributes in jQuery for $(.img) which cannot be accessed simply by:

$(.img).height() or $(.img).width() etc.

So far the code I have written is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var imgs = $('.gallery__item');//jQuery class selector
        imgs.each(function(){
          var img = $(this);
          var height = img.attr('height', img.height())
          console.log(height)
)}
)}
```

This returns the following in the console:

[image]

How would I access "accessKey" for example?

Comment: `$('someselector').attr('accessKey')` ?

Comment: incorrect, returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the attr function to get the attribute on the object you are using.

https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Example: Get access key on your object

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var imgs = $('.gallery__item');//jQuery class selector
        imgs.each(function(){
          var img = $(this);
          var height = img.attr('height', img.height())
          console.log(height)
          // get accessKey attr
          var accessKey = img.attr("accessKey");
      )}
)}
```

If the attribute hasn't been set, it will return `undefined`

This is from the https://api.jquery.com/attr/ docs

`As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set.`

Comment: incorrect, returns undefined.

Comment: @RobertCarmichael can you post a code pen example with all the code so we can inspect it?

Comment: Also @RobertCarmichael it says on the jQuery docs https://api.jquery.com/attr/ that "As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. " Since that attribute likely hasn't been set, that's why it's undefined